# How can I horizontal scrolling in less with h and l?

Tags: terminal, command-line-interface, less-unix

When I config less with -S, I can use the left and right arrow to do horizontal scrolling, but I prefer to use h and l. How can I do that? btw. I notice h in less default to help manual which is useless for me. So I just want to do a remapping in less.